# Duplicate values in list when parsing xml?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
  <row>
    <ro new="TEMP_1">TEMP_11</ro>
    <ro new="TEMP_2">TEMP_12</ro>
   <ro new="TEMP_3">TEMP_13</ro>
  </row>
 <row>
    <ro new="TEMP_1">TEMP_14</ro>
    <ro new="TEMP_2">TEMP_15</ro>
    <ro new="TEMP_3">TEMP_16</ro>
  </row>
 </rows>
```

and parser:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

context = ET.iterparse('temp.xml', events=("start", "end"))
context = iter(context)

outList = []
for event,elem in context:
    tag = elem.tag
    value = elem.text
    outList.append(value)
print outList
```

when print outList I recive :

```
 ['\n', '\n', 'TEMP_11', 'TEMP_11', 'TEMP_12', 'TEMP_12', 'TEMP_13', 'TEMP_13', '\n', '\n', 'TEMP_14', 'TEMP_14', 'TEMP_15', 'TEMP_15', 'TEMP_16', 'TEMP_16', '\n', '\n']
```

Why  I receives duplicate values in list?
How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicates because you're appending twice -- on both the start events and the end events.

Either listen to only one event type or the other, or inspect the event type as you iterate. To do the former is a one-line change:

```
context = ET.iterparse('temp.xml', events=('end',))
```

...or, if you want to listen to both event types for some other reason:

```
for event, elem in context:
    if event == 'end':
        outList.append(elem.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the start and end event happen for the same tag.  Also, what's the point of doing this:

```
context = iter(context)
```

context is already an iterator because iterparse() returns an iterator.